# Cakephp how to delete coresspond tag from bookmarks

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im working on cakephp starting tutorial Bookmarks. On the tutorial, there are 3 table Bookmarks, Tags and Bookmarks_Tags which mean it is many to many relation. I have a Bookmark name Test1, with the tag: Tag1, Tag2, Tag3. Now i want to delete Tag1 from Test1, which mean delete in table Bookmarks_Tags, but currently in the Cake Tutorial for Bookmarks, when i click delete related tag, the tag is deleted from the table Tags. How can i just delete the record on the table Bookmars_Tags?

Edit: 
Tried to bake model and controller for Bookmarks_Tags. Here is the code. Departments equivalent to bookmarks and Tags = Subject

```
public function delete($id = null)
{   
    $department_id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
    $subject_id = $this->request->params['pass'][1];
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $departmentsSubject = $this->DepartmentsSubjects->find()->where(['department_id' => $department_id, 'subject_id' => $subject_id]);
    if ($this->DepartmentsSubjects->delete($departmentsSubject)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The departments subject has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The departments subject could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

On the View

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['controller' => 'DepartmentsSubjects', 'action' => 'delete', $department->id, $subjects->id]) ?>
```

But i got the error

```
Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::delete() must be an instance of Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, instance of Cake\ORM\Query given, called in E:\BI5-ICT_3rdyear\Web dev\XAMPP\htdocs\res_manage_webservice\src\Controller\DepartmentsSubjectsController.php on line 115 and defined [CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 2064]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used `bin/cake bake` to generate the code you should have an edit bookmark action. You can visit here: `.../bookmarks/edit/1`
There you will find a `<select>` for related tags. Just don't select tag1, hit save and cakephp will remove the association.

edit:

It is possible to create a Table Class for the `bookmarks_tags` table: `bin/cake bake all bookmarks_tags`

Then you can use this Table Class to query `bookmarks_tags` directly

for example in BookmarksTagsController:

```
$bookmarksTags = $this->BookmarksTags->find()->where(['bookmark_id' => $bookmark_id, 'tag_id' => $tag_id]);
```

edit2:

> ```
> $departmentsSubject = $this->DepartmentsSubjects->find()->where(['department_id' => $department_id, 'subject_id' => $subject_id]);
> ```

this returns the query ready to be modified or executed. you can use `all()` or `first()` to execute it. `all()` returns an array all entities matching your where() and `first()` returns the first one.

```
$departmentsSubject = $this->DepartmentsSubjects->find()->where(['department_id' => $department_id, 'subject_id' => $subject_id])->first();
$departmentsSubjects = $this->DepartmentsSubjects->find()->where(['department_id' => $department_id, 'subject_id' => $subject_id])->all();
```

Comment: this is update function, even it works but now exactly what i want, i want to select Tag1 then hit delete. How can i query to the Bookmarks_Tags table? 
smt like:
$bookmark = $this->bookmarks_tags->get($bookmark_id, $tag_id );

Comment: let me try, with the fucntion DeleteTag, i should pass 2 param like Delete($id1 = null, $id2 = null). Am i right?

Comment: no, you have to pass the entity you want to delete to the tables delete method: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html

Comment: yeah but should i add 1 more parameter to the default function?

Comment: the $id in BookmarksTagsController's delete function is for `bookmarks_tags `.`id` field in the database. if you would want to delete by tag_id or bookmark_id you would have to write the code for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144632/discussion-between-notmeanymore-and-jbe).

Comment: i edited, i realize that my join table do not have the ID as primary key, i use the couple of ID attribute as my PK